# Python for Google Sheets: Create new sheet (in the same workbook) automatically and write a new dataframe into it

Tags: python, pandas, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a loop that runs 'n' times and generates 1 new dataframe in each iteration. How can I automatically create a new Google sheet (in the same workbook) every time a new dataframe is created at the end of each iteration?

I use this code to write one dataframe to a Google Sheet which is already created manually by me:

**#Code to write one dataframe to Google Sheets:**

```
cell_range_insert= 'B7'
values = df1.to_json()
body = {'values': values}
response_date= service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
    valueInputOption='RAW',
    range=cell_range_insert,
    body=dict(
        majorDimension= 'ROWS',
        values=df1.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist()
    )
).execute()
```

**#Code to generate one dataframe in each iteration:**

```
Ticker_List= ["AAPL", "GOOG", "AMZN"]
for Ticker in Ticker_List:
    values = [['=GOOGLEFINANCE("' + str(Ticker) + '", "ALL",  "1/1/2014", "2/6/2018" ,"DAILY")']]
    cell_range_insert = 'B7'
    body = {'values': values}
    
    #Send formula to Google Sheet
    service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
        valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
        range=cell_range_insert,
        body=body
    ).execute()
    
    # Readback stock data from Google Sheets:
    response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
        majorDimension='ROWS',
        range='Sheet1'
    ).execute()

    # Readback data from Google Sheets and assign it to dataframe df:
    columns = response['values'][1]
    data = response['values'][2:]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Comment: Can you provide the script of `a loop that runs 'n' times and generates 1 new dataframe in each iteration`. And, in your situation, do you want to put the values from the cell "B7" in each new sheet? Or do you want to put the values from the cell "B1"? I couldn't imagine your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, just now I have added code showing generating a new dataframe at each iteration. In this code, the loop runs 3 times-- once each for AAPL, GOOG, AMZN and write new dataframe data to the variable `df` each time. The `df` should be written to cell B7 in each of the new Sheets automatically created. The newly created sheet (after each iteration) could be named same as the value of the variable `Ticker`.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following flow.

1. Insert new sheets and put the formula to the cell "B7" to each new sheet using the batchUpdate method.
2. Retrieve values from each new sheet using the values.batchGet method.

When this flow is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```py
spreadsheet_id = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
requests = []
Ticker_List = ["AAPL", "GOOG", "AMZN"]
start_sheet_id = 123456
for i, Ticker in enumerate(Ticker_List):
    sheet_id = start_sheet_id + i
    formula = '=GOOGLEFINANCE("' + str(Ticker) + '", "ALL",  "1/1/2014", "2/6/2018" ,"DAILY")'
    requests.extend(
        [
            {"addSheet": {"properties": {"title": Ticker, "sheetId": sheet_id}}},
            {
                "updateCells": {
                    "start": {"sheetId": sheet_id, "rowIndex": 6, "columnIndex": 1},
                    "rows": [
                        {
                            "values": [
                                {"userEnteredValue": {"formulaValue": formula}}
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "fields": "userEnteredValue",
                }
            },
        ]
    )

service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body={"requests": requests}).execute()

time.sleep(5) # This is required to be used.

res = service.spreadsheets().values().batchGet(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=[f"'{e}'!B7:G" for e in Ticker_List]).execute()

# Put the values to dataframe.
for e in res["valueRanges"]:
    values = e["values"]
    columns = values[0]
    data = values[1:]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    print(df)
```

- When this script is run, 3 new sheets are inserted as the sheet names of `"AAPL", "GOOG", "AMZN"`. And the formula is put to the cell "B7" of each inserted sheet. This is run with the batchUpdate method.
- After the batchUpdate method was finished, 5 seconds are waiting. In this case, please adjust for your actual situation. 10 seconds might be suitable.
- After the wait, the values are retrieved from each inserted sheet. And, the values are put into the dataframe.

#### Note:

- In this script, 2 quotas of Sheets API are used.
- About the dataframe, this script is from your showing script. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)

Comment: It might be best to include f-strings for `ranges=[f"'{e}'!B7:G" for e in Ticker_List])` if you are working on a python3 project for this. Just that, everything else looks good.

Comment: @Diego Sanchez Oh!! Now, I noticed the important point in your comment. When I copied the script, I couldn't notice that I had removed it. I could update my answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I appreciate you incorporating the `GOOGLEFINANCE()` as a formula field and suggesting code to generate the dataframe `df`. I, in actual, create `df` after performing some mathematical calculations on the data received from `GOOGLEFINANCE()`. Thats why my original question had requested simply that if I have multiple `df` then how to add them in a new sheet? I did not want to go into `GOOGLEFINANCE()` formula (and how I create `df`) to cause confusion but I shared it because you asked.

Comment: Continued--- Just now, I have edited my original code to indicate `df_temp` to be the data read from `GOOGGLEFINANCE()` and `df` is obtained by performing calculation on `df_temp`.  Can you please suggest code with such set up in mind?  `df_temp = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)` and, 
    
    `df= <Some operations on df_temp>`

Comment: Hi @Tnaike, here is the link to the new question. I have editted this present question back to original and closing this question here. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72283662/6293211

Comment: @Sinha Thank you for your response. I would like to check it.