# Create new sheet (in the same workbook) automatically and, write a new dataframe into each in a loop

Tags: python, dataframe, google-sheets

I have a loop that runs 'n' times and generates 1 new dataframe in each iteration. How can I automatically create a new Google sheet (in the same workbook) every time a new dataframe `df` is created at the end of each iteration?

I use this code to write one dataframe to a Google Sheet which is already created manually by me. Note that, I create `df` after performing some mathematical calculations on the data received from GOOGLEFINANCE() in `df_temp`.

PS- How I get the `df` should be irrelevant to this discussion.

Simply rephrased, I would like to have help on the code for the function `Publish_df_to_Gsheet(df, Ticker)` which publishes `df` to a new sheet named with variable value of `Ticker`.

**#Code to write one dataframe to Google Sheets:**

```
cell_range_insert= 'B7'
v = df_Summary.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist()
response_date = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
    valueInputOption='RAW',
    range=cell_range_insert,
    body=dict(
        majorDimension='ROWS',
        values=v
    )
).execute()
```

**#Code to generate one dataframe (df) in each iteration:**

```
Ticker_List= ["AAPL", "GOOG", "AMZN"]
for Ticker in Ticker_List:
    values = [['=GOOGLEFINANCE("' + str(Ticker) + '", "ALL",  "1/1/2014", "2/6/2018" ,"DAILY")']]
    cell_range_insert = 'B7'
    body = {'values': values}
    
    #Send formula to Google Sheet
    service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
        valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
        range=cell_range_insert,
        body=body
    ).execute()
    
    # Readback stock data from Google Sheets:
    response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
        majorDimension='ROWS',
        range='Sheet1'
    ).execute()

    # Readback data from Google Sheets and assign it to dataframe df:
    columns = response['values'][1]
    data = response['values'][2:]

    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    
    df= <Some operations on df_temp>

    Publish_df_to_Gsheet(df, Ticker) #<--- This function prints df to a new sheet named with variable Ticker
```

[image]

Comment: I understand your expected flow as follows. You want to put 3 formulas to 3 sheets, and want to retrieve the result values of the formula, and then, you want to put the result values to the dataframe. Can I ask you about the relationship between this flow and `df= <Some operations on df_temp>` (this is your goal in this question?)?

Comment: I believe a [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) would be suitable to help you in this scenario. Specifically the requests [addSheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addsheetrequest) and [updateCells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest). You could simplify your code to a single request to the API, however that will depend on the expected output. Can you share a sample Sheet or more details on that?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, Sorry if I am not able to convey clearly. I would request that you avoid focusing on how I get the `df` and also, ignore that I am using `GOOGLEFINANCE()` formula behind the scene. I have edited my code to add function `Publish_df_to_Gsheet(df, Ticker)`. My question is simply as follows--> What should be the code of this function that takes inputs as `df` and `Ticker` and performs the task of publishing the `df` to a new sheet named as variable `Ticker`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `What should be the code of this function that takes inputs as df and Ticker and performs the task of publishing the df to a new sheet named as variable Ticker.`. But I would like to suport you. So, can I ask you about the detail of it? I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, Thanks for your willingness to help. To overcome language barrier, I have a added a photo depicting exactly what I want. I hope this helps. Dont get distracted by how I get `df`. I simply need to publish `df`s as they are created.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. When I saw your sample image, in your script, I think that 3 sheets of `"AAPL", "GOOG", "AMZN"` have already been created and the formula of GOOGLEFINANCE is put to each sheet. So, in your goal, you want to overwrite each sheet with only the values with removing the formulas. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I am afraid you may be understanding incorrect. I would request you to please forget about `GOOGLEFINANCE()`. I simplify my question even more as follows: Can you please provide code about how to create a new sheet (in an existing workbook) and print a dataframe `df` to this new sheet and, rename this new sheet as 'A'. If you could suggest code for this simple task, I can just build a loop myself.

Comment: By the way, when you reply to the comment, when you add `@username` in your reply, your reply is notified to the user.

Comment: Do you want to copy the retrieved values from `service.spreadsheets().values().get()` to other 3 new sheets?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244863/discussion-between-sinha-and-tanaike).

Comment: In your question, you use `Publish_df_to_Gsheet(df, Ticker)`. But in your showing image, you use `Publish_df_to_Gsheet(df, Ticker, Spreadsheet_id, Sheet_id)`. You want to make users create the script of this function. But, I cannot still correctly understand your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand your question, I would like to try to think of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `Publish_df_to_Gsheet(df, Ticker)` is supposed to do, however here is an idea:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SPREADSHEET_ID = '<DRIVE ID OF THE SHEET FILE HERE>'


def main():
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)


        ticker_List= ["AAPL", "GOOG", "AMZN"]

        # Loop through items in the ticker list
        for ticker in ticker_List:

            # the following request will create the Sheet tab
            # I'm using the ticker as its name in this example
            batch_update_values_request_body = {
                'requests': [
                    {
                        'addSheet': {
                            'properties': {
                                'title': ticker
                            }
                        },
                    }
                ]
            }
            request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
                spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body=batch_update_values_request_body)
            response = request.execute()

            # --------------------------------

            # the following request will update the cell B7 of the newly created Sheet tab with the formula below
            values = [
                [
                    ('=GOOGLEFINANCE("' + str(ticker) + '", "ALL",  "1/1/2014", "2/6/2018" ,"DAILY")')
                ],
            ]
            body = {
                'values': values
            }
            result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
                spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=(ticker + '!B7'),
                valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body=body).execute()
        print('DONE')

    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### References:

- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python
- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate
- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addsheetrequest
- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update